# Ruby/Rails: eval doesn't seems to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, eval

Am trying to evaluating the below code using rspec.

Given :

```
   # book = ...
   Rails.logger.info book.inspect
```

The above code prints the value of return type is `boolean` i.e `{:foo=>false}`

```
   eval(book[:foo]).should be_false
```

but that doesn't seem to work. While trying to run rspec, it throws the following exception:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: eval(book[:foo]).should be_false
>  TypeError:
>    can't convert false into String
> ```

So, how can i evaluate a boolean to a method, such as my final result would be the equivalent ?

Comment: Hm, why do you need `eval` here? What are you trying to achieve? I guess simple `book[:foo].should be_false` should be enough. The reason why you're getting an error is that `eval` accepts a string as a parameter and evaluates this string as a Ruby code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` executes passed argument interpreting it as Ruby code. What Ruby code do you think is contained in `false` object?

```
eval(false)   # cannot execute false object
eval("false") # executes a string and returns false object
```

see the difference?

i don't know what exactly are you testing but you could simply try

```
book[:foo].should be_false
```